# SPD 2010 workflow, extra file version created in Version history

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have created simple approval List workflow on document library using Sharepoint designer 2013. Workflow is 2010 based and using Sharepoint Foundation 2013.

I have enabled major version in Version Settings. Everything is working fine but when approver approve document and workflow end, it creates many extra file versions eg: 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 and so on. However version 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 are meaningful but other than that are not expected.

Please suggest where I am doing wrong.

**Edits**

[image: Page1]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share you workflow steps

Comment: @M.Qassas, added Workflow steps. Please see

Comment: @M.Qassas, can you pls see and advice?

Comment: Sorry bro for delay, How many approve required in your doc in the above workflow?

Comment: I tried to put logic for maximum 5 reviewers and 2 approvers.
Some Doc lib can have 2 Reviewers, 1 Approver, some can have 5 Reviewers and 2 Approvers also. For this I created 2 separate List ReviewerLookup(ReviewerName, Email) and ApproverLookup(ApproverName, Email) and used as lookup columns in document library. In doc lib i created 1 custom column for ReviewerStatus(ForReviwer1,ForReviwer2...ForReviewer5, Reviewed) similarly ApproverStatus(ForApproval1, ForAppoval2, Approved).

Comment: @M.Qassas, Can u please see my above comment and advice